# How to turn off WooCommerce user registration and manually create accounts?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I built an online store with WooCommerce. Now, I would like to disable WooCommerce user registration and register accounts manually. I want my store to be visible for everyone, but people should only be able to purchase something when they have an account that I created for them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just disable customer registration on WooCommerce->Settings->Accounts page.

[image]

if you want to prevent checkout for not logged in users, uncheck WooCommerce->Settings->Checkout->Enable guest checkout

[image]

Comment: this works correctly and hide registration

Comment: If I disable customer registration, people will still be able to place orders. I want them to only be able to place orders when they have an account that I created for them. Is this possible?

Comment: You didnt mention this in your question, so I assumed you know how to prevent guest checkout. I have extended my answer.

Comment: the option list for WooCommerce privacy now controls: <br>

- account creation while checkout (check)
- account creation on 'my account' page (uncheck)

this, together with disabling guest checkout, should allow for efficient account creation control.

Answer (score 2):

WooCommerce just extends WordPress' built-in user management, so you need to go to your Settings > General page and uncheck "Membership Anyone can register".